# Specify the services ServiceStack should register

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to specify the Services that SS registers rather than it picking up everything that it finds.

Given a library with say 10 services, it can be deployed on multiple servers, depending on the server its deployed on, certain services need to be enabled, these can't be in separate projects otherwise we just end up with billions of dll's to manage.

I want to be able to say "register these 3 types and routes"

Answer (score 2):

You can override the strategy used to find services by overriding `CreateServiceManager`, e.g:

```
protected virtual ServiceManager CreateServiceManager(
    params Assembly[] assembliesWithServices)
{
    new ServiceController(() => JustServicesIWant(assembliesWithServices));
}
```

Also see the wiki on [Modularizing services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services#encapsulating-services-inside-plugins) which explains how to manually register services inside plugins, etc.